# Mailchimp API (.Net Wrapper) - Auto Subscribe users

Tags: c#, mailchimp, perceptivemcapi, mcapi

I'm using the MailChimp API to subscribe users to my list (There is an opt out on the reg form) I'm using the PerceptiveMCAPI wrapper to handle this.

Once the user has registered,

```
    var ListId = "{LISTID}";

    var a = new listSubscribe(new listSubscribeInput(ListId, model.Email, new Dictionary<string, object>()));

    if(a.Execute().result)
    {
       //Do Stuff
    }
```

I need a way to auto confirm the subscription (Since the site has it's own validation methods). At the moment MailChimp sends the user an email asking them to confirm there subscription and so does the website, I need a way to auto accept the subscription for the user.

Is this possible? And how do we go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to set the MailChimp double opt in param to false to stop these confirms.

Use the listSubscribe overload which exposes it:

```
  public listSubscribeParms( string id, string email_address,
         Dictionary<string, object> merge_vars, EnumValues.emailType email_type,
         bool double_optin, bool update_existing, bool replace_interests, bool send_welcome )
```